# LinqToExcel throws Error in IE 8 (IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

This is my Code i am getting error when i am  trying to do this---
return gis.ToList();
This code actually reads an excel file and maps the data into Model CPR
Full Error is: An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

And if i am using the same code and run it in Google chrome it is working fine

Please i need help i am stuck

```
       var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(strPathName)
        {
            DatabaseEngine = LinqToExcel.Domain.DatabaseEngine.Ace,
            TrimSpaces = LinqToExcel.Query.TrimSpacesType.Both,
            UsePersistentConnection = true,

        };

        var gis = from p in excel.Worksheet<cpr>()
                  select p;
        excel.Dispose();

        return gis.ToList();
```

Comment: DatabaseEngine.Ace have you installed the new Access runtime? try Jet as type

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for your reply but i have already fixed it

Comment: and what is the solution? Post this as an answer so that you can help others who have the same issue and found your question via a search engine.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I could not see it but it was very simple my Excel path was incorrect..So you need to check the path of the excel sheet only in case when you are able to upload from Google Chrome but not from IE(Then only check the file path)

Comment: ok, post this as answer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry i can not post the answer as it belongs to my company but all i can say is do you see  new 
    ExcelQueryFactory(strPathName) check this strPathName . see if it is getting you the correct path which you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. If anyone comes to find this. The solution to this is to check the file path which you are passing to your connection. Your connection can be Oledb for excel or access or openxml.

If you receive an uploaded file, make sure not to change the file name or format from what the user uploaded. Pass the filename as is to your function. If you need to change the filename, you can always do it after the function runs